# How to scroll a page or a element using css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I want to know if there is any way to scroll a page/element using any of css property. We are able to do it with javascript with scrollTo and scrollBy, but I want to scroll using css transition properties to make an slider that will scrollleft after a given timestamp. I tried using the jquery plugin http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/, but it doesn't support scrollLeft or any scroll.

Comment: `element{
    overflow: scroll;  //or auto based on height or wid it will use scroll
    }` are you searching for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found is to transform by changing x, 
For example:

```
$('.box').transition({ x: '-40px' });
```

Make sure that overflow of box is not hidden.
http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

Answer (score 1):

You can replicate scrolling in CSS like this:

```
#parent{
    overflow: hidden;
}

#child{
    margin-left: -250px; /* Move across the page 250px (x axis) */
}
```

However, that probably isn't what you want.

The best and most common way to achieve animated scrolling is using the jQuery Javascript library:

```
$("#parent").animate({
   scrollLeft: 250
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score -1):

What i got from your question is basically you need a plugin to slide from left to right with time interval use carousel plugin in jquery it will solve your problem.

You can customize it according to your requirements. And the same effect can be done with css also but for the time interval you have to touch jquery. And you didn't mentioned that you need the slide onload or on event trigger.